# Using case for a multi-way if

Tags: haskell, coding-style

Today, I found myself typing the following code:

```
case () of
  _ | x < 15 -> ...
  _ | x < 25 -> ...
  _ | x < 50 -> ...
  _          -> ...
```

The meaning of this is straight-forward enough, but it just feels... *wrong* to utter `case ()`. Does anybody have a better suggestion?

I suppose since I'm branding on `x`, I could have written `case x`. But that still leaves me with nothing to actually pattern-match on; it's all about the guards. And that still feels weird.

Comment: What about [multi-way if](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) in newer versions of GHC?

Comment: Is something wrong with a function?   `f x | x < 15 = ... ; | x < 25 = ... ; ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `case ()`; it is the best you have for this use-case unless you want to use very recent syntactic and non-standard-extensions like GHC’s [multi-way-if](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if).

Answer (score 14):

Others have mentioned that `case` if fine and mutli-way if exists, but I'd go for a local function via a where or let statement:

```
someFunction = do
    x <- monadicOp
    let f y | y < 5  = expr1
            | y < 15 = expr2
            | y < 25 = expr3
            | True   = expr4
    f x
```

This is syntactically cleaner than the case statement solution and more portable than multi-way if.

EDIT:

In case it isn't clear, if the value being compared, `x` in this case, is already in scope when you define the guarded function (`f`) then you could just define a value instead:

```
someFunction = do
    x <- monadicOp
    let r | x < 15 = expr1
          | x < 25 = expr2
    r
```

Comment: If only one would not have to come up with a name for `r`, this would be great.

Comment: Should we make a LambdaMultiWayIf extension?

Comment: A multi-way if does not actually have a scrutinee. So what do you want to do with the anonymous argument?

Comment: I was thinking of syntax such as `\if case | < 15 -> foo ; | < 25 -> bar`.  That is, the arms of the if would be expressions of type `a -> Bool` and the if case expression has type `a -> b` where `foo, bar :: b`.

Comment: I suppose that is actually less than useful since the majority of the time you want access to the scrutinee inside the `foo` and `bar` expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit lazy evaluation to come up with something like this:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative

cases :: [(Bool,a)] -> a -> a
cases lst d = snd $ fromJust $ (find fst lst) <|> Just (True,d)

main = do
  let x = 20
      r = cases [(x < 15, putStr "15"),
                 (x < 25, putStr "25"),
                 (x < 50, putStr "50")] $ putStr "None"
    in
       r
```

Comment: You can also use list comprehensions for this, as in "concat $ [[putStrLn "15" | x < 15], [putStrLn "25" | x < "25"], ...]

Comment: Also, `fromJust $ x <|> Just y` is a quite complicated way of writing `fromMaybe y x`